# Make bootstrap collapsibles true/show when webapp starts

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I need help to make my collapsible contents opened when app starts. Can someone help me please? Sorry for my bad English.

```js
//component.ts

isCollapsed: boolean = true;
```

```html
<!--component.html-->

<div class="container" *ngFor="let List of List; let i = index">
  <a href="#List-{{ i }}" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse">{{List.prdName}}</a>
  <div id="List-{{ i }}" class="collapse">
    <ul style="list-style: none">
      <li> {{List.prdName}}</li>
      <li> {{List.prdCategory}}</li>
      <li> {{List.prdSup}}</li>
      <li> <img src="{{List.prdImage}}"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From bootstrap documentation

> `.collapse.show shows content`

So all you have to do is bind element with proper class so it would be

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let List of List; let i = index">
  <a href="#List-{{ i }}" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse">{{List.prdName}}</a>
  <div id="List-{{ i }}" class="collapse" [class.show]="isCollapsed"> <!-- if the expression will be true class "show" will be applied. -->
    <ul style="list-style: none">
      <li> {{List.prdName}}</li>
      <li> {{List.prdCategory}}</li>
      <li> {{List.prdSup}}</li>
      <li> <img src="{{List.prdImage}}"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But now i can not close it when clicked, can u help? Thanks again :D

Comment: All you have to do is add `(click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"` on html elememt that is going to be clicked.